# How to display related posts using the same taxonomy for custom types (Wordpress, Pods, Woo)

Tags: custom-post-types, woocommerce-offtopic, pods-framework

I need help to list related articles in my product page. Here what I have:

Woo Products
Custom type, created with Pods - "Artists"

Both: "Products" and "Artists" use the same (can say shared) tags taxonomy ("product_tag")

My goal is to list several articles with title, link and image from custom type "Artist" in my product page and vice versa. In other words my product_tag have to be something like "key" to recognize relationship between 2 different types.

For example.

I have product Shakuhachi and product has tag "Japan"
I have also several articles also tagged "Japan"

What I need is to display Articles tagged "Japan" in product page.

Your help to get php code is much appreciated.

Comment: Please [edit your question](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/393617/how-to-display-related-posts-using-the-same-taxonomy-for-custom-types-wordpress#) to provide more information—ideally a code sample. What have you tried? What *specific* problem are you having?

Comment: Thanks for responding on my request, I have no idea where from to start, just need to find a solution.